# How to get reproducible output with Google Closure Compiler

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

When I use Google Closure Compiler (simple mode) all functions/fields names are mangled (`A`, `B`, etc etc). That's nice, but I notice when I recompile the names are different. This means my diffs for version control often become very big, but contain useless changes.

[image: Diff Google Closure Compiler]

Is there something you can provide to the compiler to have more reproducible output, so diffs only contain minimal/actual changes?

Comment: You should not need to diff the compilation results anyway? Only *source* code should need to be version-controlled.

Comment: True, I agree on that for lot of cases. But it is still very helpful to be able to diff minified code between shipped versions.

Comment: Also QA\testing often can be sticklers on the compiled output being repeatable.